# Statistical significance of performance difference in classification models

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, f1

Is it possible to assign a p-value to the mean performance difference in three classification models? The models use the same data, same random seed, and use 10-fold cross validation. Model A has a mean F1 score of 0.70 with a standard error of 0.05, Model B has a mean F1 score of 0.75 with a standard error of 0.03, and Model C has a mean F1 score of 0.76 with a standard error of 0.02.

Can I derive p-values to measure whether these are significant improvements?

Comment: [Benavoli’s “Time for a Change” article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.04316.pdf) advocates for Bayesian approaches over frequentist ideas like p-values, but the paper does go through a number of frequentist methods.